# Use SSIS To Copy A Table's Structure And Data With A Different Name

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

Using SSIS and the example tables `myTable` and `Test_myTable` I would like to:

- Drop And Create Table the table `Test_myTable`.
- Fill `Test_MyTable` with data from `myTable`, as it stands.

Is there a particular task that does this? I was looking into the property `Expression Editor` in the `Transfer SQL Server Objects Task Editor` and thought that putting an expression on the `CopyAllObjects` property would work but I'm not sure if that is the correct path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can make use of [`Execute Sql Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141003.aspx) for this and simply execute the following statements inside your task.

Instead of Drop and Create simply Truncate table, as dropping table means you will have to give permission to users if you have some sort of restrictions and only some specific user who can access the data.

**Without Dropping the table**

```
TRUNCATE TABLE Test_myTable;
GO

INSERT INTO Test_myTable (Col1, Col2, Col3, .....)
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, .....
FROM myTable
GO
```

**Drop Table and Create**

If for some reason you have to drop table and re-create it again you could execute the following statements inside your execute sql task.

```
--Drop tables if exists

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Test_myTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE dbo.Test_myTable
GO

--Create and populate table
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, .....
INTO dbo.Test_myTable
FROM myTable
GO
```

Comment: Is it possible to generate this `Execute SQL Task` on the fly?

Comment: what do you mean by generating this task on the fly? You can create this task and execute it conditionally if that what you meant creating this on the fly.

Comment: What I mean is that the task will pull down the SQL required to generate the table, without manually changing the SQL in the Execute task.

Comment: You can populate the contents of an Execute SQL Task using expressions. In your original post you have not explained how/why this would need to be generated on the fly.

Comment: Hard coding is the way I went with this, as this answer implicitly suggests. Thanks for the help!